# Shrinkwrap modifier leaving small gaps when applied

Tags: modifiers, shrinkwrap

I'm applying the shrink-wrap modifier, but I have noticed it's not completely wrapping onto the mesh, its a few pixels away from my target object.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is because your vertex weight of t2 is just 0.8 which means: Don't use it full, just change the outer ring to weight 1 and it will work.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I do the same, and increase it to vertex weight 1, but again I get those small gaps when I zoom in. When its viewed from an angle those small gaps are not visible, so it meant to be that way? https://ibb.co/KbdSx0f

Comment: can u pls upload the repaired file again? thx

Comment: If you don't mind, can you send me back the file you edited so I can see if I get the correct result or if it's doing the same error on my Blender.

Comment: Here it is: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=2AX2k24X" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/2AX2k24X/)

Comment: there are not all set to 1. Just select single vertices and you will see that. If you set one vertex to 1, use this button here to copy to the other selected:  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4w2O.png

Comment: Great spotting, It worked. I don't know why each vertex was set to 0.8, when It seems like 1 in the vertex group. Thanks for the help!

Comment: you are welcome